# How to enable logging in FirefoxWebdriver in selenium webdriver

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver, testng, logback

I have a project in which I am using Maven, Spring, TestNG and Selenium Webdriver. I want to enable debug logging for Firefox webdriver because I am seeing inconsistent results every time I run the test. When I run via Maven test, i see the log messages from Spring and TestNG show up but I do not see anything from Selenium. Is there a way to enable logging so that i can see what is happening in selenium? I am using Logback.

Answer (score 1):

System.setProperty('webdriver.log.file',).
This dumps the Java script console log to given file.
Hope this helps